# what is difference between $ and this.$ in backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

what is difference between `$` and `this.$` in backbone Js
This is in reference to the example of book
[Addy Yosmani Book Example](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#exercise-1-todos---your-first-backbone.js-app)

Answer (score 3):

`$` is jQuery.
`this.$` rather `someView.$` is a `function` in a `View` which performs selection on DOM elements which are children of `el` of a `View`.

For example `view.$('.someClass')` (check [this](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar))  is equivalent to `view.$el.find('.someClass')` where `$el` (check [this](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el)) is a cached jQuery object for the view's element.

Ideally, inside a view you should operate on a part of DOM which descendant of view's `el`. So, `view.$` is the perfect solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

$ is jQuery, and refers to a jQuery selector.

When one uses this.$, it narrows the jquery selection to any DOM element *that is a child of* the Backbone.View.

Examples:

```
// selects the overall DOM body of your page.
$(body).append(something);

// This will not work.
this.$(body); // -> returns nothing.

var View = Backbone.View.extend({

  render: function() {

    // refers to the root element of this Backbone View.
    this.$el.append(something); 
  }

});
```

#### More data

`this.$el` is a special property Backbone applies to the view, which refers to your root element (in your case, `<p>`).

If `<p>` has a child named

```
<div class='pinkElephant'></div>
```

you can safely say

```
this.$('pinkElephant')
```

to refer to the pink elephant in *that* view, without worrying about selecting the 5 other pink elephants in the other 5 instances of your same Backbone View.

#### CSS Selector basics:

When using jQuery (and any CSS selector), to select elements by class name, you do:

```
$('.whatever');
```

By id, you do:

```
$('#whatever');
```

If three different elements have the class name whatever, jQuery will then be referring to all three elements.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer dc2. By Root element of view, you mean the el?   if the el property is <p> then this.$ has reference to <p>?

Comment: this.$el is a special property Backbone applies to the view, which refers to your root element (in your case, <p>). If <p> has a child named <div class='pinkElephant'></div>, you can safely say this.$('pinkElephant').

Comment: perfect!! Which means i can only refer to the child of the root element using this.$  For the class i guess we need to use the Dot and id we need to use # ?  <div id ='pinkElephant'></div>,  can be referred as this.$('#pinkElephant') ?

Comment: Yes - jQuery is centered around what is called a 'CSS Selector', which is what CSS uses to refer to DOM elements. jQuery uses a library called 'Sizzle' to do this.